# xdebug and MAMP horror show

Tags: php, xdebug, mamp-pro

i have been using MAMP PRO and xdebug for years (through Netbeans) and suddenly I am unable to debug. I have narrowed the issue down to the following.  Whenever I append the parameter XDEBUG_SESSION_START=anyvalue to the localhost url the page freezes, and obviously, Netbeans just waits for a connection.

for example, the following url works fine:
localhost:8888/index.php

this url freezes:
localhost:8888/anypage.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

I have tried:
-closing all copies of Netbeans.
-restarting MAMP PRO.
-restarting the Mac.(Mavericks)
-deleting MAMP temp files in /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
-creating a new MAMP host ..ex localhost1

nothing seems to fix the problem.  There is nothing wrong with the php.ini file, or Netbeans config, or xdebug config.  I am desperate.

To be clear, when i restart the computer, start MAMP PRO and nothing else (Netbeans is not running), then go here in ANY BROWSER--- 
localhost:8888/anypage.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
the page does not load and just waits.

other examples
 the following DOES load
localhost:8888/anypage.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_ST=netbeans-xdebug

the following DOES NOT load
localhost:8888/anypage.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netb

what is blocking the connection when the get parameter "XDEBUG_SESSION_START" is added???  I am ready to give up.

Comment: Can you look at the error logs in MAMP?

Comment: Since when did you ran into this problem? What has changed since then?

Comment: yes... nothing relevant in the apache_error.log or the php_error.log.  The page tries to load and then times out.

Comment: the problem started about a week ago.  I cannot think of anything that i have changed.  It also worked last night for a short period of time, (one Netbeans session), and then stopped working again.  I also tried changing the debug port to something other than 9000, and that also does not help.

Comment: also, when i change the xdebug lines in the php.ini file in order to break xdebug, the page will load; but of course, debugging will not work.

Comment: I did recently install the latest version of xcode.  Might this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by changing one line in the `php.ini` file from:

```
xdebug.remote_host=localhost:8888
```

to:

```
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1:8888
```

I have no idea why it worked with `localhost` for years, and all of a sudden did not. I suspect the installation of Xcode, but cannot prove or disprove.